# Sound is not working in backtrack5r3

Tags: backtrack-linux

How to update or install the sound driver in backtrack5r3 is the same way we do in ubuntu like to install some thing we write `sudo-apt get insatall` or the syntax is change anybody please help me out.I am running the os in vmware workstation and i have problem with sound its not working.

Comment: I think you are sound is not working.let me help you are you want to know some syntax.

Comment: No i only want to configure sound problem later on i will learn more

Comment: ok fine than follow my answer

Comment: yeah sure i will because i am looking for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok follow the link and your problem will be solved. http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=54103